# Filtering window modifyning events

Tags: objective-c, nsevent

I have this message loop:

```
while (!shutdown_now_) 
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSEvent *event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                                            untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]
                                               inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                              dequeue:YES];
        if (event) [NSApp sendEvent:event];
        // If modifying window event, do something!!! 
        [pool drain];
    }
```

I want to filter all NSEvents that modifying a window, for example move, resize, order out e.t.c. I've trying looking for the type in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/) but w/o success. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event type I was looking for is `NSAppKitDefined`:

```
while (!shutdown_now_) 
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSEvent *event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                                            untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]
                                               inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                              dequeue:YES];
        if (event.type == NSAppKitDefined)
        {
            NSLog(@"NSAppKitDefinedEvent with subtype: %d", event.subtype);
        }
        if (event) [NSApp sendEvent:event];
        [pool drain];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Filtering events is not the right approach for this.

If you don't want to allow the user to move a window, set the window's `movable` property to false.

If you don't want to allow the user to resize the window, set the window's `styleMask` to not include `NSResizableWindowMask`. Or, possibly, set its `contentMinSize` and `contentMaxSize` to its current size.

No event can directly order a window out. The window's delegate gets to decide whether or not the close button actually closes the window, by implementing `-windowShouldClose:`. If you don't want the close button to be enabled at all, set the `styleMask` to not include `NSClosableWindowMask`.

Comment: I just want to see the order of the events being received by my application window. I don't want to block them.

Comment: Well, "filtering" in your question usually means blocking them. Not all of those things correspond to events. For example, the OS X Window Server handles moving windows and only tells your app at the end of the process. If you just want to see the events that your app is receiving, set the `NSTraceEvents` default to "YES". For example, try running `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit -NSTraceEvents YES` at the command line.

Comment: Can I set this flag programmatically?

Comment: It's just a user default, so you can set it using `NSUserDefaults`. However: a) that potentially enables it persistently, and b) I'm not sure if Cocoa checks it at any time other than start-up.